# How to use Font Awesome with Bootstrap LESS theme?

Tags: theming

I have created a sub-theme, using the LESS Starterkit, of the [Bootstrap theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap). I would like to self host the [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icons and make them available to a custom module.

I have downloaded the Font Awesome project to: `sites\all\themes\MYBOOTSTRAPTHEME\font-awesome`.

Following [these](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/#custom-less) instructions, I have added the following (last four) lines to: `sites\all\themes\MYBOOTSTRAPTHEME\less\variables-overrides.less`:

```
//== Iconography
//
//## Specify custom location and filename of the included Glyphicons icon font. Useful for those including Bootstrap via Bower.

//** Load fonts from this directory.
@icon-font-path:          "../fonts/";
//** File name for all font files.
@icon-font-name:          "glyphicons-halflings-regular";
//** Element ID within SVG icon file.
@icon-font-svg-id:        "glyphicons_halflingsregular";

//** Load Font Awesome fonts from this directory.
@fa-font-path:            "../../font-awesome/fonts/";
//** File name for all Font Awesome font files.
@fa-font-name:            "fontawesome-webfont";
```

I have added the following line to my custom module:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="fa fa-camera-retro" aria-hidden="true"></span> Camera
</button>';
```

After recompiling my LESS: nothing. What am I missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Add:

```
@import "../font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less";
```

to `sites\all\themes\MYBOOTSTRAPTHEME\font-awesome\less\font-awesome.less`.